# How to find out how long someone has been on a page with jquery

Tags: jquery

I need to find out how long a user has been on a page, so for example if I've been on a page for 5 minutes I would like a pop up to show, but I'm struggling to find out how long a user has been on a page.

So far I've only got this

```
    $( document ).ready(function() {
        var startTime = new Date().valueOf();
        var loadedSeconds = (new Date().valueOf() - startTime) / 1000;
        console.log(loadedSeconds);
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`setTimeout()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout):

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
  setTimeout(
    function() {
      alert("You have been on this page for 5 minutes!");
    }, 5 * 60 * 1000);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Get the timestamp as soon as the page loads:

```
var startTime = new Date().valueOf();
```

Then run the line below whenever you want to get the timing:

```
var loadedSeconds = (new Date().valueOf() - startTime) / 1000;
```